# Magento show products in category view as dropdown list

Tags: magento, drop-down-menu, categories, magento-1.9

Here is what I want to do with Magento.

In category view, we can display products choosing either "by list" or "by grid". These are built-in options.
For one specific category, I would like the products to be displayed in a dropdown menu such as in the following picture. Plus, the user will not be able to select the grid or list view with the dropdown view as default.

[built-in category view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L0X1.png)
[dropdown menu showing products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSTV0.png)

I think I have to modify codes in list.phtml file. Could someone help me to implement the right code in order to get this result?

Comment: Your lens type selection seems to be options of products rather than what you are saying `dropdown showing products`. Is it in product detail page ?

Comment: No, the items contained in this list must be identified as Magento products. "Lens type" would be in a certain way the specific category. Just consider it is a simple title we could take out. The products related category will be called Optical Lenses.

Comment: are those what you want to filter products with or i still didn't get you ?

Comment: The picture with the dropdown list would represent the Category View page.

When you click on a product contained in this dropdown list, the Product Detail Page will be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

1. Add **lens_type** as a **custom dropdown attribute** with all lens types as attribute options/labels. Set 'Use in layered nvigation'to 'Yes'
2. Add this new attribute to the default attribute group.
3. Reindex database
4. Insert the products and select the lens type for each product.
5. Add the products to the desired category.
6. Set this category's option 'Is anchor' to 'Yes'

Now you have a layered category with a drop down option where you can choose teh lens type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alain.
The thing is the references listed have been created as Product in Magento.

Don't really pay attention to the "lens type" label in this example.
It's not an attribute but a Magento category bringing the references (Magento products) together.